# Editar xticks de un histograma en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo que editar los xticks de un histograma que he pintado con .plot, los xticks representan los meses en datetime. Me gustaría mostrar los meses, lo he intentado mediante una lista.

```
listaMeses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'] 

histograma2021 = df_logsFinalizados2021.plot(kind='bar', title = 'Histograma 2021 de viajes por mes')
histograma2021.set(xlabel='Número de viajes', ylabel = 'Mes donde finalizó el viaje', xticks = listaMeses)
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
```

Adjunto imagen del histograma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si es un error de concepto o si estoy cerca del objetivo.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la última línea de tu código, quitando la referencia a `xticks`, y añadir una línea especificando lo que quieres colocar, y donde.

Según la [documentación oficial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) de matplotlib, la forma correcta de usar xticks es:
`xticks([lista-posiciones], [lista-etiquetas])`. El codigo quedaría así:

```
histograma2021.set(xlabel='Número de viajes', ylabel = 'Mes donde finalizó el viaje')
xticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], listaMeses)
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que tu histograma solo tiene 11 meses en los datos, así que tienes que hacer coincidir la lista de meses con los xticks... te sobra diciembre.

**Edito: No se usó matplotlib.**
Erróneamente creí que se estaba usando otro módulo de python. Si se está usando **pandas**, la respuesta correcta sería añadir esta línea de código:

```
histograma2021.set_xticklabels(listaMeses)
```

Comment: buenas! el histograma lo he hecho con Pandas, y la documentación como tal es de matplotlib, por lo que no funciona. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: Lo siento, no me quedó claro al principio y pensé que usabas matplotlib. En este caso, la insturcción que debes usar en pandas es 'histograma2021.set_xticklabels(listaMeses)'

Comment: No tengo acceso a los datos y no he podido probarlo. Si te funciona, edito la respuesta para que se ajuste al resultado.

Comment: ha funcionado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Encantado de haberte ayudado.

Comment: Por otro lado, el voto negativo, sin un comentario que explique el porqué del voto, ayuda poco. Desearía que quien lo haya emitido indique los motivos. Gracias de todos modos. :-)

Comment: @JoséLuis No soy el votante (y no me gusta votar) pero te aclaro que [el voto negativo es la principal herramienta de moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5278/158880) por lo que un voto sin explicación SI es util. Sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo contigo en cuanto a que el votante debería dedicar su tiempo y sacrificar el anonimato del voto con tal de que los que fueron votados negativo entiendan el por que, eviten cometer el mismo error y mejoren como miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: Por otro lado, quizá esta pagina te pueda ayudar a saber las posibles razones del votante: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo

Comment: Si, si, entiendo como funciona, y lo acepto. Solo quería saber el motivo del voto para mejorar mis aportaciones futuras. Ningún problema por haberlo recibido, obviamente.

Comment: buenas, después de la corrección quise editar el voto negativo, ya que me ha servido de ayuda todo el proceso. Ya he podido editarlo, gracias!

Comment: Pues... gracias de nuevo!